# How to write in either HQL or JPQL?

Tags: hql, jpql

Hi I am new JPA and Hibernate concept. Can anyone help me writing the HQL or JPQL of my requested query.

For example:

```
select count(*) from (select count(u.email) from USER u where u.id='123' group by u.email having count(u.email) > 1);
```

Comment: What did you try? Can you show us your entity code? Why `select count(u.email) from USER u where u.id='123' group by u.email having count(u.email) > 1` not worked for you?